# Confused about returning a when statement

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm going through Google's Android codelabs building a dice roller app and am a bit confused on how the return type of my function getRandomDiceImage() is type Int, but it seems like the function is returning an ImageView.

I understand getting a random integer and storing it in randomInt, and I get switch statements like in standard C languages. Converting that randomInt to an R.drawable.image is throwing me off though.

```
private fun getRandomDiceImage(): Int {
    val randomInt = Random().nextInt(6) + 1

    return when (randomInt) {
        1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
        2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
        3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
        4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
        5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
        else -> R.drawable.dice_6
    }

}

private fun rollDice() {
    diceImage.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage())
    diceImage2.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage())
}
```

Comment: No, it is not a typo. `R.drawable.*` are all `Int`s. They are also annotated with `@DrawableRes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> getRandomDiceImage() is type Int, but it seems like the function is returning an ImageView.

No, it is returning an `images resource identifier`, which are `@DrawableRes int`, such as `R.drawable.dice_1` and so on.

> `diceImage.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage())`

The trick is that `setImageResource(` expects an `int` value (that is annotated with `@DrawableRes` to ensure that it is actually a drawable resource), based on that the ImageView will load the bitmap resource that the drawable identifier refers to.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you very much for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

The type of `R.drawable.dice_1` is actually `Int`, not `ImageView`. 
`R` is a static class, that holds resource ids (of type `Int`).
You can check the real value of the `R.drawable.dice_1` by pressing cmd (macOS) or ctrl (Windows) and placing cursor on the `dice_1` and you will see, `public static final int dice_1 = some_random_number` this some_random_number is the id assigned to the drawable (image) resource during the building process.

So your function `getRandomDiceImage() : Int` indeed return `Int` type.
And the `diceImage.setImageResource(getRandomDiceImage())` indeed takes id to the drawable as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using the function to determine which dice image you'll use based on the random number being generated. Note that when can also be used either as an expression or as a statement.

```
val drawableResource = when (randomInt) {
    1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
    2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
    3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
    4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
    5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
    else -> R.drawable.dice_6
}

diceImage.setImageResource(drawableResource)
```

The [setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageResource(int)) expects an `int resId` which you are passing through the when expression.